# Can I set up my Xbox One without having internet?

Tags: xbox-one

I just bought a new Xbox one, but I don't have Wi-Fi. Can I still set it up without the use of an internet connection?

Comment: "wifi" refers to wirless network technology. All XBox Ones come with a network port, allowing wired networking. Are you asking how to set up a XBox One without Internet?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just plug in a network cable and you're good to go.

According to Microsoft support, however, setting a console up for the first time requires some kind of internet connection. It cannot be done without access to the Internet.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "without" access?